# load data infile function with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have tried to import CSV file into MySQL database using PHP and MySQL load data Infile function.The query looks correct but still there is an error, while embedding it inside php code. Would you Please help me.

```
    <?php  

//connect to the database 
$host='localhost'; 
$username=''; 
$password=''; 
$database_name='cricket'; 
$connection=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password,$database_name); 
if(!$connection)
{
    echo "no connection made"; 
}

// 
else {

$query="LOAD DATA INFILE 'cricket.csv'
     INTO TABLE cricket_batsman
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
     mysql_query($query); 
}




?>
```